# how to make apps fast as c++ and as crossplatform as web apps?

Tags: c++, build, web-applications

As a personal project I would like to write a large, computationally expensive simulation with some graphics and user inputs at runtime. For that reason it was clear to me that I will be using C++ as my main language. (I also have a personal preference to use C++.)

Then I realized I would like the simulation to be as broadly available (crossplatfrom) as it can be. I guess it might be tedious for potential inexperienced users to use build instructions. For example, as far as I know, a windows user would have to install Make, Git, and a C++ compiler to run all the necessary commands in the terminal.

I have searched for a bit and now I think my only choices are:

- assuming the user is skilled enough to follow c++ build instructions
- pasting the whole .exe file to OneDrive
- compile to .wasm (but that would require me to learn it and probably
  set up a server right?)
- ignore C++ assume javascript can handle the computation and host it
  on github.io

My experience is pretty narrow and (I think) I would like to keep it as close to C++ as I can.

I also plan to make similiar projects in the future (with crossplatform and computationally expensive requirenments.)

Maybe I am missing something? Any input is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Put it into a Docker container?

Comment: You mention a "web app" in the title but then go on to talk about having the user compile an exe. Which is it? Will it run on a web server or a local pc?

Comment: Well the thing about C++ is that it will be compiled to a specific target platform and the resulting exe will thus not be portable. And in a way "fast" and cross platform are mutually exclusive, to be fast you need to know the hardware in detail and optmize for it.

Comment: Define "*some graphics*"... 2D? 3D? accelerated? animations? Perhaps try looking into [game engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines), they have a lot of 3D graphics support built-in.

Comment: @rustyx 2D graphics.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am considering both options. I used the term web app to highlight on how many platforms it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to either use WebAssembly (.wasm) as you yourself suggested, or distributing a binary executable for each platform you want it to be available to. This way, users don't have to recompile the code on each platform. Github provides a way to distribute these precompiled binaries, though I personally have not tried it. If you want to go the wasm way, take a look at Emscripten (https://emscripten.org/),  I believe that project provides an extensive toolset that will recompile a many apps from C++ to wasm without too much work. I know it's not a complete answer but hope it helps.